# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, tkinter, float

> Erro: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Estou enfrentando este erro, sei que envolve tipos de variaveis, mas não sei como fazer para o Entry receber um valor do tipo float

```
#TRANSOFORMAÇÃO DE COORDENADAS GEODÉSICAS EM COORDENADAS PLANAS – SISTEMA UTM

from tkinter import *
import math
class SAD69:
    def __init__(self,master):


        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid(row=0)
        self.A = 1.0050526248
        self.B = 0.0050632321
        self.C = 10.628107*pow(10,-6)
        self.D = 20.821897*pow(10,-9)
        self.E = 3.9327535*pow(10,-11)
        self.F = 6.5553406*pow(10,-14)
        self.alpha = 111133.3486
        self.delta = 0.021986053
        self.beta =  16.03895511
        self.eps = 3.114475*pow(10,-5)
        self.gama = 16.83348972
        self.x = 4.1531106*pow(10,-8)
        self.pi = 3.141592654
        self.a = 6378160
        self.k = 0.9996
        self.p0 = 57.2957795131
        self.e=0.0066945419
        self.n = 6382845.536
        self. l = 0.0067396609
        self.entry1=Entry(frame)
        self.entry1.grid(row = 4, column =1)
        self.label2 = Label(frame,text='Digite a latitude do ponto >>').grid(row=4,column=0)
        self.entry2=Entry(frame,text='LONGITUDE do ponto')
        self.entry2.grid(row=4, column =3)
        self.label3 =Label(frame,text='Digite a longitude do ponto >>').grid(row=4,column=2)
        self.bt1 =Button(frame,text='Converter',fg='blue',command=self.GEOPLAN)
        self.bt1.grid(row=3, column=1)
    def GEOPLAN(self):
        fia =(self.entry1.get())
        la = (self.entry2.get())
        S = self.a*((1-self.e)*((self.A*(fia*self.pi)/180)-(0.5*self.B*math.sin(2*fia*0.017453292))+(0.25*self.C*math.sin(4*fia*0.017453292))-((1/6)*self.D*math.sin(6*fia*0.017453292))+((1/8)*self.E*math.sin(8*fia*0.017453292))-(0.1*self.F*math.sin(10*fia*0.017453292))))
        I = self.k*self.S
        dl = 3600*(51-la)
        p = dl*0.0001




root = Tk()
root.title='TRANSOFORMAÇÃO DE COORDENADAS GEODÉSICAS EM COORDENADAS PLANAS – SISTEMA UTM'

x=SAD69(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: o Erro ocorre na funcao GEOPLAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro significa que uma variável contendo uma sequência (lista, tupla, string, etc) está sendo multiplicada por um float. No Python, se você multiplica uma sequência por um número inteiro, ele repete aquela sequência várias vezes:

```
>>> [1,2,3] * 4
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> (10,20) * 3
(10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20)
>>> "teste" * 5
'testetestetestetesteteste'
```

Mas se você tenta multiplicar por um float, ocorre esse erro:

```
>>> [1,2,3] * 1.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Na sua função `GEOPLAN` as variáveis `fia` e `la` são resultado da chamada de `Entry.get`, o que retorna o texto de um controle. O erro então ocorre porque você está tentando multiplicar esse texto por um float, sem antes convertê-lo num número.

Experimente converter essas duas variáveis em floats antes de usá-las:

```
fia = float(self.entry1.get())
la = float(self.entry2.get())
```

Também pode ser interessante checar seu formato antes da conversão, para o caso do usuário ter entrado com algo que não é um número (não tenho experiência com o TKinter, então não sei se ele pode ou não fazer essa validação/conversão automaticamente).

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas ele aponta que nao foi possivel converter:/.

Comment: Na verdade parceiro, eu baixei a ultima versao do python e ele realmente converteu da forma que vc falou.